# How can I get GPS location in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Can you tell me, how can I get GPS location in iPhone.

Thanks.

Comment: You should make even a minimal attempt to search Apple's documentation before asking a question. And this question is exceedingly general.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Implement CLLocationManagerDelegate and write this function and call this in viewDidLoad Method of your viewController.

```
-(void)startLocationManager
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate=self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
 {      
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [newLocation coordinate];
    double dblLatitude = coordinate.latitude;
    double dblLongitude = coordinate.longitude;     
 }
```

Comment: in iOS 6 didUpdateToLocation is deprecated so use **didUpdateLocations** instead

Answer (score 4):

If you are using CLLocationmanager, make sure you check to see if location Service is enabled first. I would do this to get the current location:

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) 
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D *currentLocation = locationManager.location;

    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager release];
}
```

If you are using mapView, you could get current location using:

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
CLLocationCoordinate2D *currentLocation = mapView.userLocation.coordinate;
```

Answer (score 2):

You use CoreLocation framework.
   Here you can get sample code http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/